# Расчет динамики показателей

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Как корректно рассчитать динамику по показателям?

Имеется датафрейм `df1`:

```
id  year  sales assets
qwe  2014  110    50
qwe  2015  115    53
qwe  2016  117    52
qwe  2017  120    55
dfe  2014  76     45
dfe  2015  80     47
dfe  2016  83     50
dfe  2017  85     50
```

Нужно рассчитать динамику по продажам и динамику активов `df2`:

```
id  year  % sales %assets
qwe  2014  1       1
qwe  2015  1.04    1.06
qwe  2016  1.01    0.98
qwe  2017  1.02    1.05
dfe  2014  1       1
dfe  2015  1.05    1.04
dfe  2016  1.03    1.06
dfe  2017  1.02    1
```

Не получается рассчитывать коэф-ты динамики учитывая, что самый меньший год в колонке `year` берется за базовый.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```py
In [51]: res = (df[["id","year"]]
                .join(df
                      .groupby(["id"], as_index=False)
                      [["sales","assets"]]
                      .apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[0])))
```

---

```py
In [52]: res
Out[52]:
    id  year     sales    assets
0  qwe  2014  1.000000  1.000000
1  qwe  2015  1.045455  1.060000
2  qwe  2016  1.063636  1.040000
3  qwe  2017  1.090909  1.100000
4  dfe  2014  1.000000  1.000000
5  dfe  2015  1.052632  1.044444
6  dfe  2016  1.092105  1.111111
7  dfe  2017  1.118421  1.111111
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!